# How to compile coffeescript using react native packager?

Tags: coffeescript, react-native

I would like to develop a react native app using coffeescript but I can't find any information on how to compile it using the default react native packager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that use a gulp file compile Coffee to vanilla JS and then the RN packager will watch out the JS files. 
https://github.com/jacobbubu/coffeeReactNative

Comment: I ended up using [this project](https://github.com/pct/react-native-template) which got me started. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Compile it to JavaScript first with `coffee -c`, then build with react native like nothing happened. Problem solved!

Comment: Yeah I know I can use grunt/gulp to even do this automatically but the question was using the packager so I won't have multiple files or have to deal with compiling myself.

Comment: I don't think React-Native packager have something like `coffee-loader`. You can use `Webpack` if you don't like both `foo.coffee` and `foo.js` exist, but the RNpackager can't do that at this time.